# how to remove a specific word from a list of folders

Tags: windows-xp

[image]

please  help me remove particular word from a list of folders not files specifically not files 
remove karbonn from all the folder names without modifying internal data

Comment: `Right click > Rename...`

Answer (score 2):

If you install PowerShell on your Windows XP machine, this would be very easy.

In the PowerShell terminal, you would need to move to the directory where you'd want to change the folder names and then use this command `Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace “Karabonn“,”” }`

It seems like you'd then have some folders that start with `-` or `_` so you could then run the command again to remove those characters.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a program to do this a while ago.  Heres a screenshot

[image: FileSmith]

I will upload it somewhere tonight for you to download.

EDIT
[Heres a link](https://pacificblue.software/download-file/file-smith)